# How to display the ID's of all the leaves related to a given level along with this level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tree structure:

```
CARS (ID = 3)
    | AUDI (ID: 5, ParentId: 3)
        | DIR1 (ID: 9, ParentId: 5)
        | DIR2 (ID: 7, ParentId: 5)
        | DIR3 (ID: 8, ParentId: 5)
    | FIAT (ID: 10, ParentId: 3)
    | FORD (ID: 11, ParentId: 3)
        | DIR4 (ID: 12, ParentId: 11)
    | RENAULT (ID: 6, ParentId: 3)
    | TOYOTA (ID: 4, ParentId: 3)
```

I need to display the ID's of all the leaves related to a given level along with this level as follows:

| ID | Name | ID2 | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | CARS | 3 |  |
| 3 | CARS | 5 | AUDI |
| 3 | CARS | 9 | DIR1 |
| 3 | CARS | 7 | DIR2 |
| 3 | CARS | 8 | DIR3 |
| 3 | CARS | 10 | FIAT |
| 3 | CARS | 11 | FORD |
| 3 | CARS | 12 | DIR4 |
| 3 | CARS | 6 | RENAULT |
| 3 | CARS | 4 | TOYOTA |
| 5 | AUDI | 5 |  |
| 5 | AUDI | 9 | DIR1 |
| 5 | AUDI | 7 | DIR2 |
| 5 | AUDI | 8 | DIR3 |
| 9 | DIR1 | 9 | DIR1 |
| 7 | DIR2 | 7 | DIR2 |
| 8 | DIR3 | 8 | DIR3 |
| 10 | FIAT | 10 |  |
| 11 | FORD | 11 |  |
| 11 | FORD | 12 | DIR4 |
| 12 | DIR4 | 12 | DIR4 |
| 6 | RENAULT | 6 |  |
| 4 | TOYOTA | 4 |  |

This is a dynamic structure, users can delete and add leaves so I need a function or procedure.

I have created the following code but maybe there is a better, more elegant way to get the results:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE 
              (
                  ID int, 
                  Name varchar(255), 
                  ParentId int, 
                  Level int, 
                  Leaf int
              )

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES (3, 'CARS', NULL, 1, 0),
       (4, 'TOYOTA', 3, 2, 1),
       (5, 'AUDI', 3, 2, 2),
       (6, 'RENAULT', 3, 2, 3),
       (7, 'DIR2', 5, 3, 1),
       (8, 'DIR3', 5, 3, 2),
       (9, 'DIR1', 5, 3, 3),
       (10, 'FIAT', 3, 2, 4),
       (11, 'FORD', 3, 2, 5),
       (12, 'DIR4', 11, 3, 1)

;WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT  
        ID, Name, ParentId, Level, Leaf 
    FROM 
        @T
), cte2 AS
(        
    SELECT  
        ID, Name, ParentId, 1 AS [Level],                  
        CAST((RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(ID, 15, 0)))) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Ids              
    FROM    
        @T t1
    WHERE   
        ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT  
        t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.ParentId, M.[level] + 1 AS [Level],                 
        CAST((M.Ids + ',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(t2.ID, 15, 0)))) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Ids
    FROM    
        @T AS t2
    JOIN 
        cte2 AS M ON t2.ParentId = M.ID  
)
SELECT 
    B.ID, B.Name AS Name,
    cte2.ID AS ID2, cte2.Name
FROM 
    cte2
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1024)') AS gId
     FROM
         (SELECT    
              CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Ids, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String) A
     CROSS APPLY 
         String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) AS A
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT CAST(gId as int) AS G_ID) AS G_ID
INNER JOIN 
    @T B ON B.Id = G_ID
```

Comment: How can you tell that "DIR1 (ID:9)" is *inside* "AUDI (ID:5)"? The data doesn't seem to provide any indication of that.

Comment: Seem like the data we have is expected reault, but we don't have sample data. I would *assume* that the `ParentId` is the link, but that data isn't exposed in the data we have.

Comment: There is a field in @T called ParentId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you are after?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  ID, Name, ID id2, Name Name2, ParentId, 1 AS [Level] 
      , CAST(STR(ID,15,0) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Ids 
    FROM    tbl
    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT  m.ID, m.Name, t2.id, t2.name,  t2.ParentId, M.[level] + 1
      , M.Ids + ',' + STR(t2.ID,15,0)
    FROM tbl AS t2
    JOIN cte AS M ON t2.ParentId = M.ID2  
)
select ID, Name, id2, Name2, level, replace(ids, ' ', '')
from cte
order by id, ids;
```

All paths from a node.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=89304611068220ee9f237e0a06823d56)

Comment: Thanks for your help, the code looks better.